# Active record query using prepopulated form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an EVENT app and I'm trying to create an INVITE from within an EVENT view.

```
1    class InvitesController < ApplicationController
2
3        def create
4            user = User.find_by(:name => params[:name])
5           event = Event.find(params[:event])
6           if user
7               @invite = Invite.new(attendee_id: user.id, attended_event_id: event.id )



    events/show.html.erb

    <%= form_tag invites_path do %>
            <%= label_tag :name %>
            <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
            <%= hidden_field :event, params[:event], :value => params[:id] %>
```

I'm getting "UNDEFINED METHOD 'ID' FOR #"  on line 7 for the event.id call.  If I hard define event on line 5 to event = Event.find(1) it works fine.

My debug says that the variable is passing through fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed line 5 to event = Event.find_by(:id => params[:event].)